# Magento Remove the tab in customer edit page

Tags: admin, magento-1

Here I attached the picture showing what I'd like to remove (shopping cart tab in the customer admin page).[image]

Answer (score 3):

Below was tested and worked.

Assume that your custom module is **Mynamespace_Mymodule**

Override the block **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php**

In order to override add the below XML content in **app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    ....
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tabs>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
       .....
</config>
```

Now create the block **app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php** with below content.

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs
{
    public function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        parent::_beforeToHtml();
        $this->removeTab('cart'); // Put the name of the tab which you want to hide
        $this->_updateActiveTab();
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

Finally clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The default tabs in the customer edit menu are added in the core file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php
```

To remove the "Shopping Cart" tab, you need to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs` and override the `_beforeToHtml()` function without this portion of code:

```
$this->addTab('cart', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart'),
    'class'     => 'ajax',
    'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/carts', array('_current' => true)),
));
```

Comment: i extended the customer module and remove the 'cart'  and 'wishlist' tab in my extended file. even after clear the cache still is not working. i am waiting for your answer.

Comment: The following solution has more details on how to remove tabs from customer/edit. Extending things on the adminhtml side of things is a little different than on the regular customer view pages. They also use `removeTab('tabname')` instead of simply omitting the part where the tab is added. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604062/how-to-remove-tabs-from-customer-edit-page-in-magento-backend